# Call Servlet methods based on input of the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My JSP page has 2 input boxes:

1) Amount to deposit.

2) Amount to withdraw.

Due to Javascript validation, **the user can input in either of the boxes**. Based on the inputs from the jsp page, I'm trying to call the appropriate servlet method. However, its been a frustrating experience, so far.

The challenge I'm facing is, if I enter deposit amount I get a `NumberFormatException` for the withdraw amount and vice-versa. How do I eliminate this?

**.jsp page**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorShades.css">

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function myfunc1(){
            var deposit = document.getElementById("deposit");
            if(deposit.value.length >0){
                document.getElementById("withdraw").disabled = true;
            }

            else{
                document.getElementById("deposit").disabled = false;
            }
        }


    function myfunc2(){
            var withdraw = document.getElementById("withdraw");
            if(withdraw.value.length >0){
                document.getElementById("deposit").disabled = true;
            }

            else{
                document.getElementById("withdraw").disabled = false;
            }
        }


    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="DepositWithdrawServlet" method="post"> 

        <div>
            <label>Account No:</label>
            <input type="text" name="accountNo" class="input_boxAdj"  id="account" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>


            <div>
                <label>Enter amount to deposit:</label>
                <input type="text" name ="depositAmt" values="deposit" class="input_boxAdj" id="deposit" onblur="myfunc1()" />

            </div>  
        <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>


            <div>
                <label>Enter amount to withdraw:</label>
                <input type="text" name ="withdrawAmt" values="withdraw" class="input_boxAdj" id="withdraw" onblur="myfunc2()"/>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>



        <div> 
                <button class="button">Submit &raquo;</button>     
                <span><button class="button">Reset &raquo;</button></span>
        </div>


    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Servlet code:**

```
package com.banking.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.banking.dao.WebBankProjectDao;
import com.banking.dao.WebBankProjectDaoImpl;
import com.banking.pojo.WebBankTemporaryPojo;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DepositWithdrawServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/DepositWithdrawServlet")
public class DepositWithdrawServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DepositWithdrawServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Reached inside servlet");

        WebBankTemporaryPojo tempPojo = new WebBankTemporaryPojo();         
        WebBankProjectDao bankdao = new WebBankProjectDaoImpl();

        int initialBalance = 0; 
        int finalBalance = 0;

        int depositAmt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("depositAmt"));
        System.out.println("Deposit Amt: " +depositAmt);

        System.out.println("Value" + (depositAmt>=0));


        if((depositAmt>=0 && request.getParameter("withdrawAmt")==null)){

                if(initialBalance==0){
                    out.print("<body style='color:red; font-family:Times New Roman; font-style:italic; font-size:25px'>");
                    initialBalance = depositAmt - 1000;
                    out.print("Amount of Rs.1000 will go as MINIMUM BALANCE to be maintained");
                }

                else{
                    finalBalance = depositAmt + initialBalance;

            }
        }

        tempPojo.setDepositAmt(request.getParameter("depositAmount"));
        bankdao.depositAmt(finalBalance);



        int withdrawAmt = 0;        
        int withdrawAmount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmt"));
        System.out.println("Withdraw Amt: " +withdrawAmount);

        if(withdrawAmount>0 && request.getParameter("depositAmt")==null){


            if(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"))>finalBalance){
                out.print("<body style='color:red; font-family:Times New Roman; font-style:italic; font-size:25px'>");
                out.print("Oops !! Please deposit some funds before you can withdraw"); }

            else if(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"))<0 || Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"))==0){
                out.print("<body style='color:red; font-family:Times New Roman; font-style:italic; font-size:25px'>");
                out.print("The minimum amount you can withdraw is Rs. 100");
            }

            else if(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"))%100==0){
                out.print("<body style='color:red; font-family:Times New Roman; font-style:italic; font-size:25px'>");
                out.print("You should enter in the multiples of 100 to withdraw money"); 
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"))>finalBalance){
                out.print("Sorry, you have insufficient funds !!"); }
            else{
                withdrawAmt = finalBalance - Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"));
            }

        }


        tempPojo.setWithdrawAmt(request.getParameter("withdrawAmount"));
        bankdao.depositAmt(withdrawAmt);


    }

}
```

**[image: DAOImpl.java]**

```
@Override
public boolean withdrawAmt(int accountNo) {
    Connection con = DBUtility.getConnection();
    String sql="update temporarytransaction  set withdrawAmt=? where 
    accountNo=?";

    WebBankTemporaryPojo tempPojo = new WebBankTemporaryPojo();

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, tempPojo.getWithdrawAmt());
        stmt.setString(2, tempPojo.getAccountNo());

        int no=stmt.executeUpdate();

        if(no>0){
            System.out.println("amount withdraw successfull");
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean depositAmt(int accountNo) {
    Connection con = DBUtility.getConnection();
    String sql="update temporarytransaction set depositAmt =? where accountNo=?";

    WebBankTemporaryPojo tempPojo = new WebBankTemporaryPojo();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, tempPojo.getDepositAmt());
        stmt.setString(2, tempPojo.getAccountNo());


        int no=stmt.executeUpdate();

        if(no>0){
            System.out.println("amount deposit successful");
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       return false;
}
```

Comment: NumberFormatException occurs when the value passed to parseInt is non-numeric or can't otherwise be parsed. Ensure that you sanitise your input before calling the method. For example trim any white spaces, remove any currency signs i.e $,£ etc.

Comment: @GilesThompson - **I made sure that input is free of white spaces, & any currency signs i.e $,£  etc, but there is no improvement in the output.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply wrap this in a null check:

```
int depostAmt = 0;
if(request.getParameter("depositAmt") != null){
        depositAmt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("depositAmt"));
}
```

Comment: **Doesn't help. Tried this, before posting the question.**

Comment: It could perhaps be the empty string which would change the above code to if(!StringUtils.isBlank("request.getParameter("depositAmt")){...}

Answer (score 1):

You should use the BigDecimal class to do monetary calculations. Simply sanitise the input from your clients then call new BigDecimal passing in the amounts i.e `BigDecimal depositAmt = new BigDecimal("22.50");` To ensure you are receiving valid amount to process log the amounts passed in to the screen i.e `Logger.getLogger(name.of.your.class).log(Level.info,"Amount passed in was {0}",amountPassedIn);` That was you can be certain only numeric values are provided.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since I'm new to Servlets and JSP, the implementation of your method seems to be a bit challenging, if not out of proportion.

Comment: What challenging about it? I'm merely suggesting you output/log the data you are receiving from the client in order to ensure it is in fact numeric. And again, I'll reiterate, you should NOT being using int or Integer to do monetary operations as rounding errors may result. You should use the BigDecimal class - thats what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

use request.getParameter("withdrawAmount")!=null and
 request.getParameter("depositAmt")!=null before parseInt.
because it may be possible that either of you will get null.